# How to create a table rows with an array in angular?

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

I have an array from 1 until 35:

```
numbersArray = [1,2,3,4,....,35]
```

I want to create a html table like the following:

```
---------------------------
1  |2  |3  |4  |5  |6  |7
---------------------------
8  |9  |10 |11 |12 |13 |14
---------------------------
15 |16 |17 |18 |19 |20 |21
---------------------------
22 |23 |24 |25 |26 |27 |28
---------------------------
29 |30 |31 |32 |33 |34 |35
---------------------------
```

I used the following:

```
<tr *ngFor="let number of numbersArray;">
    <td>{{number}}</td>
</tr>
```

How can I add `</td></tr><tr><td>` tags after 6 items in `*ngFor`?

Comment: can you change your data structure to array of arrays like [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11,12,13,14], ...] ?

Comment: Check if [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42095567/4911842) helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution without customize `Pipe` or changing in numbersArray

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"> 
    <td *ngFor="let col of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">
    <div>{{numbersArray[(row -1) * 7 + col - 1]}}</div>
    </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/VUw3j27EGVzZv8NZykWr?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

If it has to be a table and grouped into row you should make the data represent it like so.

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oJzVxu4Arrzxfduh6O8e?p=preview)

*data*

```
let cells = [];
for(var i =1; i <= 40 ; i++){
   cells.push(i);
   if((i % 7) == 0) {
      this.rows.push(cells);
      cells = [];
   }
}
```

table

```
  <table>
     <tr *ngFor="let cells of rows;">
        <td *ngFor="let c of cells;">{{c}}</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either prepare data for that or create custom pipe like:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'chunks' })
export class ChunksPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(arr: any, chunkSize: number) {
    return arr.reduce((prev, cur, i) => (i % chunkSize) ? prev : prev.concat([arr.slice(i, i + chunkSize)]), []);
  }
}
```

and then use it the following way:

```
<tr *ngFor="let chunk of numbersArray | chunks: 7">
  <td *ngFor="let number of chunk">{{number}}</td>
</tr>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/SZ6RL9glZhLRdbBeXd0O?p=preview)**

Without any preparations and pipes you can do the following in a generic way:

```
<table *ngIf="{ colNum: 7 } as ctx">
  <tr *ngFor="let _ of [].constructor(+(arr.length/ctx.colNum).toFixed()), let row = index">
    <td *ngFor="let _ of [].constructor(ctx.colNum), let col = index">
      <div>{{arr[row * ctx.colNum + col]}}</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Replace `7` with your desired number of columns.

**[Ng-run Example](http://%3Ctable%20*ngIf=%22%7B%20colNum:%207%20%7D%20as%20ctx%22%3E%20%20%20%3Ctr%20*ngFor=%22let%20_%20of%20%5B%5D.constructor(+(arr.length/ctx.colNum).toFixed()),%20let%20row%20=%20index%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%20*ngFor=%22let%20_%20of%20%5B%5D.constructor(ctx.colNum),%20let%20col%20=%20index%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%7B%7Barr%5Brow%20*%20ctx.colNum%20+%20col%5D%7D%7D%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3C/td%3E%20%20%20%3C/tr%3E%20%3C/table%3E)**

Comment: what about this one: 
`<tr *ngFor="let row of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]">
        <td *ngFor="let col of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];let dayObject = daysInMonth[(row * col) - 1]">
          
        </td>
      </tr>`But It doesn't know `row`

Comment: What do you mean `it doesn't know row`?

Comment: Angular throws exception: `Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("`  https://plnkr.co/edit/VUw3j27EGVzZv8NZykWr?p=preview

Comment: You can't define such variable within ngFor. https://plnkr.co/edit/bTLBo28fV83HU3uYlJCq?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Reduce your array into rows of item:

```
  numbersArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21];
  rowsArray = [];

  ...

   this.rowsArray =
      this.numbersArray.reduce((memo, item) => {
        let itemsPerRow = 7;
        if (!memo.length) { return memo = [...memo, [item]]; }

        let lastItem = memo[memo.length-1];

        if (lastItem.length < itemsPerRow) {
          memo[memo.length-1] = [...lastItem, item];
        } else {
          memo = [...memo, [item]];
        }

        return memo;
      }, []);
```

html:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of rowsArray">
    <td *ngFor="let item of row">
      {{ item }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```