# Split Array by part base on N count

Tags: javascript

How to create a chunks of array by part base on given parts count..

for example ..

```
var myarray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var bypart = 3 ;

makechunks(bypart);
```

expected output is ..

```
[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]
```

from large array to 3 small arrays

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/SZ6RL9glZhLRdbBeXd0O?p=preview https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007912/how-to-create-a-table-rows-with-an-array-in-angular/44008439#44008439

Comment: why does the last array contain 4 elements?

Comment: because the requirement is to regroup the array by parts. for example by 3 parts. from large array to  3 small arrays

Comment: what should happen with 11 elements?

Comment: output could be  [1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

Comment: No its not a possible duplicate . I so it already and tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in way in either javascript or angular.

I assume you want all parts to be roughly the same size.

```
function splitArray(array, groups) {
    var sets = [];
    var groupsize = array.length / groups;

    for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < groups; i++, j += groupsize) {
      sets[i] = array.slice(j, j + groupsize);
    }

    return sets;
}
```

For your given input `splitArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 3)` the result will be `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]`

Comment: I had misunderstood the question at first. Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use only a fraction of the length and add it to the index.

```js
function chunk(array, count) {
    var result = [],
        size = array.length / count;
        i = 0;

    while (i < array.length) {
        result.push(array.slice(i, i += size));
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 3));
console.log(chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: FYI - you're passing in `count`, but not actually using it in the function. You've got a lovey magic number instead

Comment: @ChristopherMoore, well spotted :-)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to google?

Here is what you need:

```
var createGroupedArray = function(arr, chunkSize) {
    var groups = [], i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i += chunkSize) {
        groups.push(arr.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
    }
    return groups;
}
```

Usage example:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];
var groupedArr = createGroupedArray(arr, 4);
var result = JSON.stringify(groupedArr);
// result: "[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14]]"
```

Taken from:
http://www.frontcoded.com/splitting-javascript-array-into-chunks.html

**UPDATED:**

```
var makechunks = function(arr, chunksAmount) {
    var chunkSize = Math.ceil(arr.length/chunksAmount);
    var groups = [], i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i += chunkSize) {
        groups.push(arr.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
    }
    return groups;
}
```

Comment: Links are not preferred as they tend to die. Add the contents in your answer.

Comment: i already try it ..  so close but .. not the correct function as i expected to use.

Comment: I've added an updated version, where you put chunksAmount, but not a chunkSize. May be that is what you need?

Comment: it makes the element limit by 4 . so that the result make more than the given size .. 
like this sample as i am  testing
chunks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 3));
the goal is from large array to 3 small arrays

Comment: I've added an updated example, where the 2nd parameter takes the amount of chunks, instaed of the chunk size.

Comment: Thanks! :) it also work now. useful line
var chunkSize = Math.ceil(arr.length/chunksAmount);