# Render table(2D array) N*M size

Tags: angular

I would like to render table giving the array, e.g. `let results=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` looking like:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

but have no idea how to set number of rows properly, using such a template

```
<table>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let result of results">
    <tr>
      <td>{{result}}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

I get the table with one row in fact. How to manage rows number for such a case? It may seems trivial but hard to manage due to lack of experience with Angular2+.
Thank you!

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/q9olLVsEcGrskv8oQkV7?p=preview

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007912/how-to-create-a-table-rows-with-an-array-in-angular/44008439#44008439

Comment: thank you, @yurzui, it seems exactly what I need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cases like this, I like to use a nested array and iterate on the top array as a `<tr>` element, and then iterating on that "row" to display the elements.
Assuming you change your array to:

```
let results=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Your view would be:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of results">
    <td *ngFor="let item of row">{{item}}</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

If you can't transform your array to a nested array, you can create a function to do that and call it in the template like:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of transformToNestedArray(results, 3)">
```

And this function would be defined in your code as:

```
transformToNestedArray = (arr, cols) => {
  let newArray = [];
    while(arr.length){
      newArray.push(arr.splice(0, cols))
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

The result from that function will only be used in the view and will not modify your "results" variable.

Comment: Thank you for quick response, but I need to handle exactly flat array...

Comment: I edited the answer to add the javascript code that turns your 1D array into a 2D array only to display it. It doesn't modify your original array :)

Comment: Thank you, Bruno, such an approach solves the issue!