# Show two different index in same row different column

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ngfor

I have a list of image they come from an json array with 7 elements :
The key of image is

```
 <ion-grid>
    <ion-row    *ngFor="let image of imageList; let i = index;">
      <ion-col>
           <div >
 
            <img  [src]="image.imageUrl"  />
         </div>      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
          <div  >
            <img  [src]="image.imageUrl"  />
        
          </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
 
    </ion-grid>
```

But this code show me the same pic per row , I have tried to set image[i] on the first col and image[i+1] on the second but nothing.

I want to show two image per row like this but without same image.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007912/how-to-create-a-table-rows-with-an-array-in-angular

Comment: Looks but not exatly the same problem.

Comment: Trust me, it's the same. My answer with chunks pipe should solve your task

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? Display 2 images next to each other? If that so, why not just set the `size=6` on the ion-col and just iterate over the col instead of the row?

Comment: try `imageList[i].imageUrl` and `imageList[i+1].imageUrl` for img src.

Comment: @kian I tried this but I got undefined imageUrl

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<ion-grid>
 <ion-row    *ngFor="let image of imageList; let i = index;">
  <ion-col>
       <div >
        <img  [src]="imageList[i]?.imageUrl"  />
     </div>      </ion-col>
  <ion-col>
      <div  >
        <img  [src]="imageList[i + 1]?.imageUrl"  />
      </div>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Inside de *ngFor loop, the `image` will always be one image for every iteration. You should iterate the `imageList` and use the index to access the images from `imageList`. Hope it makes sense